# Function of return -1

Tags: java, return, return-value, linear-search

Basically what does this return -1 do ?

for an example :

```
int linear[] = {4, 21, 36, 14, 66, 91, 8, 22, 7, 81, 77, 10};
int key = 77;
for (int i = 0; i < linear.length; i++){
  if (linear[i] > key)
    return -1; //here
  else if (linear[i] == key)
    return i;
}
```

- i understand return 1 and return 0 well . but return -1 ?
- what if the question sounds like this :

Show the way of solving the linear search based on the code given ?

Comment: Note that searching an ordered array can be done in `O(lg(n))` time rather than `O(n)` time using a binary search.

Comment: This array does not seem to be sorted.

Comment: @peter.petrov it seems to me it should be(although I agree it is not) otherwise the rest of the code does not make much sense

Comment: @peter.petrov I noticed the same thing - this is odd code, because if it were sorted, a binary search would make sense, not linear.  And if it's not sorted, you can't jump out early.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case it says/indicates that linear[i] is smaller than your key.

In some occasions it might also indicate that a key is not found.

This is a widely used convention (I mean returning -1 in such cases).

Comment: I don't quite agree. I believe we are performing a search for a given value in the array and that we return `-1` if we don't find `key`. It also seems the author relies on the array being sorted, thus this `if`.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I don't know if the author is the OP (if the two coincide). OP asked what this code does. What I wrote is what the code does not what we think it should do.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Otherwise, yeah, the code does not make much sense to me too (overall, I mean).

Comment: well the caller of the function will have no notion of what `linear[i]` is so you can not document it as `returns -1 if linear[i] is bigger than key`. Maybe a better way to say it is `returns -1 if an element equal to key is not found before a greater element is found`

Comment: In *this case*, -1 was supposed to indicate that the array does not contain the requested number.

Answer (score 6):

I believe this function is meant to take a sorted array and returns the index of a given key if it is found in the array and return `-1` if there is no matching element in the array.

EDIT: to avoid confusion - in the example you show `linear` is not sorted. This means that it will not do what I describe above. If `linear` is not sorted, then the function will do the following:

- if there is an element in `linear` such that all prior elements in `linear` are strictly smaller than `key` and it is equal to `key`, the function will return its index
- Otherwise if there is an element greater than `key` the function will return `-1`.
- Otherwise the return value is not defined in the code snippet you provide.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum I know that is why I say `is meant to take a sorted array` the function does not make much sense the way it is used here.

Comment: it's also not really a function - you would expect to see `key` and `linear` passed to a function - not hardcoded

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum I consider it a function mostly because of the last `}`. Please have another look at my edit. I hope it makes the answer more precise.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a shorthand for when the value is not found in the sorted array. With the assumption that it's sorted, if a bigger value than the one you're searching for is met, it's useless to continue the search, so it quits and returns -1 (0 or a positive number would be ambiguous)

Answer (score 1):

-1 as a special value is a hold-over from earlier days of programming.  It's a common convention that indicates an error condition.

See the trouble with an integer return type is that it doesn't give you a way to signal that the function couldn't successfully run.  So usually part of the contract of many methods is that they return a positive integer (or zero).  Negative values (or specifically -1) means that something about the premise of your function call wasn't right.

For example, if you do this, you'll get -1:

```
System.out.println("This string doesn't contain a semicolon".indexOf(";"));
```

You're asking for the index of a string that isn't in what you're searching.  Clearly we can't return any positive integer, so we return -1.

Answer (score 1):

The code will likely not do what is expected:

Even though 77 is in the array - it will not be "found" because the 91 before it will "hide" it.

So this will return -1, if the element is not found, or a higher value preceded the key in the list

```
int linear[] = {4, 21, 36, 14, 66, 91, 8, 22, 7, 81, 77, 10};
int key = 77;

for (int i = 0; i < linear.length; i++){
  if (linear[i] > key)                        // when linear gets to 91 - this is true
    return -1; //here                         // this will return -1 before 77 is found
  else if (linear[i] == key)
    return i;
}
```

To search the whole (unsorted) array - the following code is needed:

```
for (int i = 0; i < linear.length; i++)
{
  if (linear[i] == key)
    return i;
}
return -1; // not found
```

So in a function - return will stop executing the function when the return is reached and the caller will get the value returned.

So, if this was in a function `foo()` and code had `x=foo();` then x would be -1

Typically both the key and the array would be passed in to foo: `x=foo(77, linear);`